# Any way to change the current archive log in postgres

Tags: postgresql

My server(postgres 9.0) is showing this error:

> 2014-11-13 23:59:19 EST: DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: cp
>   -i pg_xlog/00000001000000630000006A /var/log_archive/00000001000000630000006A

The '00000001000000630000006A' xlog was gone long time ago. I have recovered the read-only server. I need the master to reset the existing log position and move to the latest xlog and archive it for the read-only server.

For example, if the current xlog is '000000010000006300000077', I'd like the master to forget '00000001000000630000006A' and start archiving 000000010000006300000077 from now.

Thanks.

Comment: As far, the workaround I do is to do a check for the file existing before cp as suggested by other threads.

Comment: "was gone long time ago". What exactly happened? when you "recovered (from?) the read only server" what exactly did you do?

Comment: Not quite sure what happened to old WAL logs, supposedly they can be removed only when 'archive_command' is run successfully. I didn't find those pg_xlogs on master server or the standby server. To recover the read only server, I used the way from these links  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hot_Standby.

Comment: Without a description of exactly what you did, I doubt I can help you.

Comment: Something mixed here. Let me clarify it. The read-only server has been recovered already by following the urls I mentioned. The only issue I can see is the error in the subject. '00000001000000630000006A' is not there any more by some reason. '00000001000000630000006A' is a quite old one. So my question is how postgres know which pg_xlog it should be copied over.

Comment: Sorry, without the exact commands you followed (not just a link to the manual) I cannot help you. Maybe someone else will respond. Good luck.